# Slick Slider - API to load images into slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, slick.js

I am creating an api of images which looks like the following:

```
{
  "images": [
    { "src": "http://placehold.it/100x100" },
    { "src": "http://placehold.it/100x100" },
    { "src": "http://placehold.it/100x100" }
  ]
}
```

I have integrated slick slider (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and the following code to append the images to the slider.

```
const jsonUrl = "./images.json";
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (json) {
  var imgList = "";
  $.each(json.images, function () {
    imgList += '<div class="slide"><img src= "' + this.src + '"></div>';
  });

  $('.videos-slides .slide').append(imgList);
});
```

The HTML markup is as follows:

```
<div class="videos-slider">
  <div class="videos-slides"></div>
</div>
```

I understand the logic of how this works but I need a push in the right direction to achieve this - The problem I'm getting is that the images are loading underneath each other. Partly because when I append the images to `.video-slides .slide`, it doesn't add the extra classes that are added by slick slider when you add a  into the html itself.

I've initialised slick slider before all of the code above FYI.

Comment: It has a dedicated method named `slickAdd` for this purpose, and the documentation has an example how to use it.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, i have managed to fix the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dedicated method `slickAdd`, the issue has been resolved.

```
const jsonUrl = "./images.json";
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function (json) {
var imgList = "";

$.each(json.images, function () {
  imgList += '<div><img src= "' + this.src + '"></div>';
});

$('.sy-videos-slides').slick('slickAdd', imgList);
});
```

Comment: After 5year this comment saved my @ss

Answer (score 0):

You will need to refresh your slider after appending HTML

when you do

```
  $('.videos-slides .slide').append(imgList);
```

do this too

```
$('.mySlider')[0].slick.refresh(); //replace .mySlider with actual DOM element
```

see demo - https://jsfiddle.net/5ox31m2a/2993/